# Why value is not displaying in form field redux

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I want to restrict user to enter only digit if someone try to enter any alphabet will remove by using the below function :

```
export const digitOnly = (value) => {
try {
    if (!value) {
        return value
    }
    const onlyNums = value.toString().replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
    console.log(onlyNums);
    return onlyNums;
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

}

In my Form i added field like :

```
<Field 
                        name="otp" 
                        type="text"
                        component={loginProcess.renderField} 
                        label="Enter OTP*"
                        normalize={loginProcess.normalizePhone}
                        className="user_name"
                        label="OTP"                            
                        errorLabel="OTP"
                    />
```

issue is that normalize is not reflecting the value in field. But if I change this line const onlyNums = value.toString().replace(/[^\d]/g, ""); to const onlyNums = value.toString().replace(/[^\d]/g, "-"); it replace the alphabets with -

Why this is happening?

Comment: replace should indeed work fine also with the space. can you share a bit more context ? e.g. why the function is called digitOnly but in the field is called normalizePhone? does it happen with any kind of input? can you check in your redux store what that value is ? (e.g. using redux devtools)

Comment: the function name is a typo mistake, but same normalize function I am using with any other form it is working fine.